# Uncertainty/Error Estimates from RMSE and Confusion Matrix

Tags: linear-model, error, pymc

1. Would it be advisable to use the F1 score as an 'error', to represent both omission and commission error rates in this areal masking process?
2. Would it be advisable to treat the RMSE and F1 as standard deviations, and add them in quadrature to produce an error estimate?
3. Would it be appropriate to then use this error term as the `sd` parameter for the likelihood, as in `likelihood_x = pm.Normal('x', mu=true_x, sd=x_err, observed=x)`?

My model depends on two inputs: one is the result of a binary classifier, another is an estimate of a real number from a physical model. I have error estimates from both the binary classifier, in the form or a confusion matrix, and from a validation study of the physical model, in the form of RMSE as a percent. The classifier is used to mask the physical model results spatially, then I find a sum of the physical results within the mask. Now I want to use my model output in a Bayesian linear regression, as in [this post](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/dealing-with-multivariate-x-errors-in-both-x-and-y-and-posterior-predictive-for-y/654). There is error in both the x and y variables.

I'm out on a statistical limb, given my background. Thank you in advance.